# Menu bar not showing - Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, aquamacs

Image is self-explanatory. How do I get the OS Menu Bar to show in Aquamacs (3.2 GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2)?

[image]

Comment: I've never used Aquamacs. Does `M-x menu-bar-mode` help?

Comment: It did the trick after restarting Aquamacs , @Chris! Thanks much.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've added this as an answer, along with something to put in your config file (usually `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or `~/.emacs`) to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactively, you can try `M-x menu-bar-mode`, which toggles the menu bar. If you wish to always show the menu bar, you can add this to your configuration file:

```
(menu-bar-mode)
```